# How can I save my Windows system restore points to a DVD?

Tags: windows, backup, system-restore

Is there any way to copy the restore points to another location? A virus could delete the restore points so I want to put them in a separate directory and save them for later use. My OS is Windows Vista.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ["`Complete PC Backup`"](http://www.ehow.com/how_5943623_make-permanent-restore-point.html) option to create a permanent DVD backup of your system.
I have a feeling that this may be the only way to prepare for a restore from DVD.

There will be third-party tools to do a complete drive backup which will restore your Windows back to that point completely (I mean the system partition). You might want to invest in such a tool and backup with a schedule.

Windows System Restore points are stored in the system drive itself.
I think you cannot move them around and leave them to be usable later.
<sup>would like to know if someone has done this safely</sup>.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the answer to this question: "[How can I archive a restore point permanently](https://superuser.com/questions/73940/archive-a-restore-point-permanently)?" The poster points out how to mount a Volume Shadow Copy, which is how restore points are saved on the drive. Since I've never tried it, I don't know if there is anything special you need to do to copy them back to the system and restore from there. Let us know if you try it.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't have access to the folder after doing the above, make sure you have User Account Control turned all the way to the lowest of the four settings. Then repeat the steps above, click through the warnings, and open the System Volume Information folder. Tadaaaa!  :)

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)