# How to prevent windows from deleting specific old custom restore points

Tags: windows, windows-8, backup, system-restore

Windows automatically deletes old restore points.  How do I prevent windows from deleting some particular custom restore points.

[Here is a similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/73940/archive-a-restore-point-permanently), which talks about talking the backup of restore points, but it didn't answer how to restore the backed up restore points.

Comment: this can't be prevented. Use recImg to create a permanent restore: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/b8/archive/2012/01/04/refresh-and-reset-your-pc.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Windows doesn't delete any restore point created by windows or user. They get deleted if the restore points take up much of the memory allotted to the restore points.

So, to create new restore points Windows needs to delete the old ones as to create new restore points. If you do not want Windows to delete the restore points, then you can increase the memory for restore points or can use some software like CCleaner which can delete all restore points (based on user choice). Also you can backup restore points, but it's very complicated to restore them from the backups.

Answer (score -2):

As far as I know the best way to prevent the loss of any given restore point is to have two spare external drivers, one for windows's file history which in my own opinion is better than third party softwares, and the other for recovery purposes (windows installation media: ISO, USB Flash Drive, etc...).

The answer "jonsca"(or "user285626") provided couldn't be more contradictory... if windows doesn't delete restore points then who does when there isn't enough space allocated for it to create a new restore point?

Comment: While the last part is good info, this is posted as an answer when it should be a comment.